# Консоль закрывается после выполнения определенной фунцкции

Tags: c#

Я создал обыкновенный консольный калькулятор. Я хочу, чтобы после выполнении какой-нибудь функции, программа позволяла выполнить другую, тем самым не закрываясь.

```
        `string again = "yes";
        while (again == "yes")
        {
            double a;
            double b;
            double total;
            char oper;

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("MathCalculate is working");
            Console.ResetColor();

            Console.WriteLine("\nEnter first number:");
            a = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter operator:");
            oper = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Enter second number:");
            b = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            if (oper == '+')
            {
                total = a + b;
                Console.WriteLine("Addition " + a + " and " + b + " equals: " + total + ".");
            }

            else if (oper == '-')
            {
                total = a - b;
                Console.WriteLine("The difference of the numbers " + a + " and " + b + " equals: " + total + ".");
            }

            else if (oper == '*')
            {
                total = a * b;
                Console.WriteLine("Multiplication of numbers " + a + " on " + b + " equals: " + total + ".");
            }

            else if (oper == '/')
            {
                total = a / b;
                Console.WriteLine("Division of numbers " + a + " on " + b + " equals: " + total + ".");
            }

            else
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Console.WriteLine("Error");
                Console.ResetColor();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue work with calculator? (yes/no)");
            again = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }`
```

Comment: можно было немного проще, но и в таком виде проблемы быть не должно, если не напутали с буквами, которые имеют одинаковое отображение в разных раскладках, например `e` в слове `yes`

Answer (score 0):

В конце вы запрашиваете разрешение на продолжение цикла и тем самым вне зависимости от ответа переписываете переменную `again`, которая и отвечает за ваш бесконечный цикл. В случае если вы ошиблись хотя на один символ, то срока будет иной.

Console.ReadLine() сразу возвращает строку и конвертировать ее в строку еще раз не нужно.

Предлагаю сделать следующий вариант.

```
while (true)
{
    /* 
     * Ваша логика
    */

    var answer = Console.ReadLine();
    if(answer?.ToLower() == "no") break;
}
```